# Difference between Button and Link in React

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I want to convert my `<button>` to a `<Link>`. But I keep getting an error.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `to` supplied to `Link`.
```

My code looks like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const SignOutButton = () =>
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={auth.doSignOut}
>
  Sign Out
</button>

export default SignOutButton
```

I want something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const SignOutButton = () =>
<Link
  to={auth.doSignOut}
>
  Sign Out
</Link>

export default SignOutButton
```

Because the styling of the Link is different and just to know why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Link>` (from `react-router-dom`) takes `to` as either a `string` which is the path that your users get redirected to when they click the link

**to: string**

> A string representation of the location to link to, created
>   by concatenating the location’s pathname, search, and hash properties.

Or an object with:

**to: object**

> An object that can have any of the following properties:
>
> **pathname**: A
>   string representing the path to link to.
>
> **search:** A string
>   represenation of query parameters.
>
> **hash**: A hash to put in the URL,
>   e.g. #a-hash.
>
> **state**: State to persist to the location.

You are passing it `auth.doSignOut` which I'm guessing is a function, which in turn causes the prop validation to fail.

---

**Perhaps instead of a router link you are just looking for an `a` tag?**

```
<a onClick={auth.doSignOut}>Sign Out</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Panayiotis, this really helped me understand. It worked with an <a> tag.